# Laravel chunking of results out of sort memory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I receive an exceptionally large JSON from our frontend API. When converted to an array it's approx. 12k items with a lot of stuff on each of the items.

I am saving it into a database json column and that's that.

A Laravel queue job is started that fetches that json, casts it to array and iterates over it to create a record for each for further processing later. Creating of the records sort of works each time.

```
// $this->import holds the model from the db and data is the huge JSON
// that is automatically cast to an array

$this->import->data->each(function ($site, $key) {
    // This method would call Item::create([]); and will create a model for each
    $this->createItem($site);
});

 WebsiteImportItem::query()
     ->byImport($this->import)
     ->chunk(1000, function(Collection $items) {
          $items->each(function(WebsiteImportItem $item) {
              // This stays commented for my tests
              // $this->setCurrentSite($item)->validate();
          });
    });
```

If I just have the first part of the job I can run it many times even simultaneously and would work every time. When I introduce the chunking it starts throwing `Out of sort memory`.

After it stops working it wont even go through the first part of the job with `Memory allocation` error.

It starts working again after I `php artisan cache:clear`

What can I do to optimize this enough for it to be working?

Comment: maybe just break up the json array into elements in sql instead?

Comment: Do you have access to update the maximum memory of the application? Is there a specific objective to perform chunking?

Comment: You can always do `ini_set('memory_limit', 'yourvalue');` at the beginning of the script. Just make sure you don't exceed your useable memory. Otherwise, I would probably find a way to chunk it or save it differently before you process it later.

Comment: @ysth This is a good approach - chunk it in SQL and save it into the other table and then still iterate through it over chunks?

Comment: @AaronT I do have access, but what if someone uploads 20 JSON?

Comment: @aynber What other options for chunking do I have?

Comment: This might seem like something to be delegated to a queue and worker instance if you're handling that level of volume. It might be better to save the JSON files and then process it in the background.